# How to host Flutter web app which has multiple pages in firebase and use web like routing

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-go-router

I have been facing issue while hosting my Flutter website using firebase.
I am using go router, The website has has initial splash screen with route `/` and another screen dashboard with route `/dashboard`.

After hosting the website, It works fine if I directly go to the link i.e. `https://confess-9fc81.web.app` and then it redirects to `https://confess-9fc81.web.app/dashboard` screen.

but if I want to refresh the screen it throws 404 not found error.

the router.dart code is,

```
import 'package:confess/screen/dashboard/screen/dashboard_screen.dart';
import 'package:confess/screen/splash/screen/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:responsive_framework/responsive_framework.dart';

//navigator key
final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

// GoRouter configuration
final router = GoRouter(
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  initialLocation: SplashScreen.routeName,
  restorationScopeId: 'confess',
  errorBuilder: (context, state) => const ResponsiveBox(
    widget: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('404'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: SplashScreen.routeName,
      builder: (context, state) => const ResponsiveBox(widget: SplashScreen()),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: DashboardScreen.routeName.replaceAll('/', '').trim(),
          builder: (context, state) => const ResponsiveBox(
            widget: DashboardScreen(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);

class ResponsiveBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const ResponsiveBox({
    required this.widget,
    super.key,
  });
  final Widget widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaxWidthBox(
      maxWidth: 1980,
      child: ResponsiveScaledBox(
        width: ResponsiveValue<double>(
          context,
          conditionalValues: [
            Condition.equals(name: MOBILE, value: 450),
            Condition.between(start: 800, end: 1100, value: 800),
            Condition.between(start: 1000, end: 1980, value: 1000),
          ],
        ).value,
        child: BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(
          context,
          widget,
          dragWithMouse: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The expected solution would be to be able to refresh any route as we do it in normal websites.